Swap from SPL -> SOL is sending the input amount * 10^9
Currently I am running into an issue when I try to send the transaction to swap 5 tuusdc to sol on solscan it shows up as "swap 5,000,000,000". When I send a transaction to swap sol -> spl the inputAmount is correct and the transaction goes through. For spl -> sol however I think that after the serialization or deserialization it is modifying the inputAmount. Has anyone else ran into the same issue and curious how we should handle spl- -> sol swaps differently.

can you please provide your code snippet?
